# How to download images from multiple URLs?

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I'm trying to download images from multiple links,  I've tried using the code below, which throws no error, but only the last image is getting downloaded.

Here is my source code:

```
import requests

image_url = [
  "https://vision-images-store.s3.amazonaws.com/internship/zipper/view_1/3213e9e9da734c268db6bed4b76ea411.jpg",
  "https://vision-images-store.s3.amazonaws.com/internship/zipper/view_1/3a4e9c2704bb46afb5a43c3231974e04.jpg",
  "https://vision-images-store.s3.amazonaws.com/internship/zipper/view_1/48d93cb06ede452fbab83495a4ff17a6.jpg",
  "https://vision-images-store.s3.amazonaws.com/internship/zipper/view_1/c7d91a112c6341eb84ed8e62ea4d6aa8.jpg",
  "https://vision-images-store.s3.amazonaws.com/internship/zipper/view_1/5cb6f2cdd3a244af9d9640be6e65b4f0.jpg",
  "https://vision-images-store.s3.amazonaws.com/internship/zipper/view_1/b5804b834f2945dabd87892df695f5b2.jpg",
  "https://vision-images-store.s3.amazonaws.com/internship/zipper/view_1/c1a05e6fa0b24a2490b10b80760dae83.jpg"
]

for img in image_url:
  file_name = img.split('/')[-1]
  print("Downloading file:%s"%file_name)
  r = requests.get(img, stream = True)
  with open("file_name", 'wb') as f:
    for chunk in r:
      f.write(chunk)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code isn't working  because you're using a string `"file_name"` and not the variable, try this instead:

```
import requests

image_url = [
  "https://vision-images-store.s3.amazonaws.com/internship/zipper/view_1/3213e9e9da734c268db6bed4b76ea411.jpg",
  "https://vision-images-store.s3.amazonaws.com/internship/zipper/view_1/3a4e9c2704bb46afb5a43c3231974e04.jpg",
  "https://vision-images-store.s3.amazonaws.com/internship/zipper/view_1/48d93cb06ede452fbab83495a4ff17a6.jpg",
  "https://vision-images-store.s3.amazonaws.com/internship/zipper/view_1/c7d91a112c6341eb84ed8e62ea4d6aa8.jpg",
  "https://vision-images-store.s3.amazonaws.com/internship/zipper/view_1/5cb6f2cdd3a244af9d9640be6e65b4f0.jpg",
  "https://vision-images-store.s3.amazonaws.com/internship/zipper/view_1/b5804b834f2945dabd87892df695f5b2.jpg",
  "https://vision-images-store.s3.amazonaws.com/internship/zipper/view_1/c1a05e6fa0b24a2490b10b80760dae83.jpg"
]

for img in image_url:
 file_name = img.split('/')[-1]
 print("Downloading file:%s"%file_name)
 r = requests.get(img, stream=True)
 # this should be file_name variable instead of "file_name" string
 with open(file_name, 'wb') as f:
    for chunk in r:
       f.write(chunk)
```

Answer (score 0):

In [this project](https://github.com/adriano-pinaffo/download_images) I took a similar approach to download a number of images from a site, from a list of URLs acquired on the site itself.

[image]